# Accessing client and server app on diff machine on local network

Tags: javascript, node.js, network-programming, localhost

I want to route client app requests coming from a different machine on my local network, to the server on my dev machine.

I have a client side app running on port 8080, and a server app running on port 3000.

I am accessing the client app from another machine on the local network using:

`machineName:8080`

However, the requests from the client app are obviously all being sent to `localhost:3000` rather than `machineName:3000`.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you not simply run the client on your machine?

Comment: I can, but the API requests are being sent to localhost:3000 rather than the actual hostname

Comment: It doesn't matter.  If you're running it locally then the machine name will be resolved exactly the same as localhost and become 127.0.0.1

Comment: Did you mean my machine as in not a diff machine? Because I asked in the question how this is done using a diff machine @Archer

Comment: Yes I did mean that, because it's the easiest way to resolve your issue without having to modify the server application.

Comment: @Archer Ok I actually did solve the issue modifying just the client app. See the answer below. LMK your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I had to forward my API requests on my client app as follows:

```
'http://' + window.location.hostname + ':3000'
```